# Determine the parameters so that the function is continuous in R

Tags: limits, analysis, functions

I got this problem i've tried to solve but i don't know how to proceed.
$$\begin{cases} 3\sin(4x)&&\text{if }x\leq 0 \\ mx+q&&\text{if }x>0 \end{cases}$$
Find the value of $m$ and $q$ so that the function is continuos in R.

I've tried this
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} 3\sin(4x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}mx+q$$
So that the $q$ value equals to $0$ but I don't know.

Comment: "the $q$ value equals $0$" looks like a good conclusion.  You might want to consider whether the function would then be continuous for any value of $m$

Comment: Hi! I've taken the step of editing your MathJax. Note that (as with regular LaTeX), MathJax treats any letters as variables, unless they are part of a control sequence (or are enclosed in a `\text{}` command)).

Comment: Further comments, if you want to make these changes: $1$. It is generally not considered obligatory to use parentheses in $\sin 4x$, even though it's technically less ambiguous that way. $2$. The reals are often denoted either $\mathbb{R}$ (`$\mathbb{R}$`) or, more traditionally, $\mathbf{R}$ (`$\mathbf{R}$`).

Comment: @BlobFish If my answer was satisfactory in resolving your question, can you please vote for it and/or click the checkmark to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in determining that $q = 0$.

Since we are taking the limit at $x = 0$, and anything times $0$ is still $0$, the coefficient of $x$ does not have any effect on the answer. Therefore, $m$ can be any real number, and $q = 0$ (as mentioned above). We can represent this answer as $\boxed{q = 0, m \in \mathbb{R}}$ or $\boxed{q = 0, m \in (-\infty, \infty)}$.